# JNI + Type Conversion (Signed Short to Unsigned Short, for example)

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, type-conversion

I'm in JNI hell with typeconversions out the wazoo:

Here's the general flow of things:

- read a file and it returns me with a
  1D array of floats.
- convert these
  floats[] to shorts[] (*4095, I want a
  12 bit number)
- pass these shorts[] to
  C, which duplicates them in an
  unsigned short array
- flip bits around
  to make big-endian java bits
  little-endian for image processing
- convert these new numbers to a
  double[] (/4095)
- pass the double[] to the
  image processing function
- convert processed double[] back to short[] (*4095)
- flip bits in short[] back to
  big-endian
- convert short[] back to float (/4095), pass back to java
- pass float[] to int
  conversion which arranges the bits to
  ARGB_8888 format

There has GOT to be a better way to do this.

On top of all that crap, it's not working. I'm getting back all noise, which I feel might be a result of the unsigned short arrays in C (useful for bit-switching) and the signed short arrays in C. This is a major problem.

So I guess my general question is, how can I improve this so that I'm not dealing with all of these problems converting between types, including signed/unsigned issues.

Anything you can suggest will be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the benefit of having an intermediate `short` representation, since the Java code works with floats and the C code works with doubles.  I would do something like this:

```
float[] floats = readFile();

// Convert to little-endian doubles
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * floats.length);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
DoubleBuffer db = bb.asDoubleBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < floats.length; ++ i) {
    db.put(i, floats[i]);
}

doImageProcessing(bb); // Native method

// Convert double values to ARGB
int j = 0;
int[] argb = new int[floats.length / 4];
for (int i = 0; i < floats.length; i += 4) {
    int a = Math.max(0, Math.min((int) (db.get(i) * 256.0), 255));
    int r = Math.max(0, Math.min((int) (db.get(i+1) * 256.0), 255));
    int g = Math.max(0, Math.min((int) (db.get(i+2) * 256.0), 255));
    int b = Math.max(0, Math.min((int) (db.get(i+3) * 256.0), 255));
    argb[j++] = (a<<24)|(r<<16)|(g<<8)|b;
}
```

Comment: The only reason shorts are in this workflow is because the native function requires little-endian bit arrangements while the data is initialized in big-endian.

Comment: You're right though, I don't need that intermediate step. Thanks. This is great.